# With FlutterFire cloud_functions, are all requests POST?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, flutter-web

I am writing an API using Firebase Functions for a Flutter Web application. I cannot see any way to use the FlutterFire cloud_functions.dart package to call my functions using any http method other than 'POST.' Am I missing something?

With this Firebase function:

```js
export const hello = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    cors(req, res);
    functions.logger.info(req.method);
    switch (req.method.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'get':
            res.status(200).send({'data': 'get', 'error': false });
        break;
        case 'post':
            res.status(201).send();
        break;
        case 'options':
            res.status(200).send();
        break;
        default:
            res.status(405).send({error: true, data: {}, message: 'method not allowed'});
    }
});
```

Is there any way to have code like

```dart
HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('hello');
HttpsCallableResult result = await callable();
print(result.data);
```

issue a GET request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requests made to callable functions with the Firebase Functions SDK are always POST and can't be changed.  You can see exactly what it's doing if you read over the [protocol specification for callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference).

If you want to use the Firebase Functions SDK to invoke a function, you must also define your function using `onCall` instead of `onRequest`, as described in the [documentation for callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

If you define your function with `onRequest`, then you should use a standard HTTP client library to invoke it.  The Functions client SDK will not work.

You can't really mix and match `onRequest` and `onCall` functions - they have different use cases and implementation details.

Comment: Thanks for this. I wound up using onCall for all functions called directly from my client-side code and onRequest for the webhooks that an external API needed. onCall is different than writing REST APIs but it winds up being less effort.